# Issue running Gulp on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie

MAINTAINER Ewan Valentine <ewan@theladbible.com>

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN apt-get update -y && \ 
    apt-get install -y \
    curl

RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs

VOLUME ["/var/www/admin/src"]

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/admin/src
WORKDIR /var/www/admin/src

RUN npm install -g gulp

ENTRYPOINT ["gulp"]
```

However, when I run `$ docker-compose run gulp` I get the following error:

```
[10:47:49] Local gulp not found in /var/www/admin/src
[10:47:49] Try running: npm install gulp
```

I'm using docker-compose and this container is linked to a volume where the source code is kept, which all runs fine otherwise.

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in your `admin/src`-dir so that you have all dependencies in `node_modules`? Else it won't find any local gulp.

Comment: Interestingly, when I add `RUN npm install` after setting my WORKDIR (so's `npm install` is being ran in my project root), npm complains it can't find my package.json file, which is definitely in my project?

Answer (score 0):

I was liking to the wrong volume! Sorted now.